# How to install Debian GNU/Linux without Removing Windows or Formating

Tags: linux, debian, gnu

I want to install debian on my computer, and I already have Windows on it. Is there any way i can install Debian on a partition without removing what's in it or formatting? I can't get past the setup, and I'm afraid to lose any data.

Comment: That's Ok, I Got it, You just have to select Manual Partitioning so you can resize the partition's disk to clear some space for the Distro.

Comment: Just to be clear, you should ***always* have a backup of any data you care about.** *Particularly* when you're doing something like fiddling with partitions or installing an operating system! Far too many people come here asking "how do I recover my data?" when simply backing it up in the first place would have negated any need to recover and greatly reduced their stress level.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for a quick feel around of what Debian is like, then perhaps you might be OK to `run a live CD/DVD version of Debian` which you can download from here .. Any of [the .iso files listed here](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/) will boot and run from CD/DVD .. The different names are self-explanatory depending on what Desktop type you want (gnome, kde, xfce,lxde), or you can get greedy and try them all (in turn) .. :-)

If you are indeed set on sharing your disk between Debian and Windows, then you will have to modify your disk partitions because both cannot exist together in the same partitions.

I suggest you first download one of the free `partition management applications` available online .. install in windows, and use to adjust your disk partitions, so you can free up some space for the Debian installation. [This is a good one](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/) ..

`A partition management tool allows you to resize your disk partitions safely, and without losing data.`  Your objective is to free up some space, and Debian can run happily in very little space but aim to allow for at least 10-20GB (if you have enough space on the disk)

When you have enough space, you can then run the debian install (you can also start an install from a live CD) .. During the installation choose to install in free space.  `Debian7 uses grub2 and can generate a boot menu that will allow you to easily choose the OS to run at start up` ..

Hope this is useful ..